# Need count to refresh

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

How would I go about to get the count to refresh by itself. Currently I have it set on a page and I am using Iframes with a meta refresh tag but I am trying to get away from Iframes.

```
<?php $stmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT COUNT(*)AS rows_cnt FROM requests WHERE User=:user AND status='Received' AND Date=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->execute(array(':user' => $user2));
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {  echo $row['rows_cnt'];  
 } ?>
```

Comment: WTF?! `AND User='".$user2."'` Check again how to create a prepared statement.

Comment: you possibly can do it with jquery .

Comment: I know how to create a prepared statement this is my old code I will put new code in.

Comment: Use Ajax/JS for that.

Comment: is there an example you can show me?

Comment: The Web is full of examples. Google "php ajax refresh javascript" and maybe add "auto refresh". http://www.sitepoint.com/auto-refresh-div-content-jquery-ajax/ being the first link that popped up.

Comment: Thanks Fred I will check it out.

Comment: You're welcome Veronica.

Answer (score 0):

well here is Little example of how you done auto refreshed div

Js :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#divtoload').load('pagetoberefreshed.html').fadeIn("slow");//place html or php page  that you want to be loaded into div
}, 50000); // refresh every 50000 milliseconds
</script>
```

html :

```
<div id="divtoload">
 loading....</div>
```